What is the probability that a 75% chance will occur at least once out of three runs?
If A has a 75% chance of occurring otherwise B will occur what is the probability that A will occur at least once out of three runs.  I would also like if you also answered with an equation to solve this with different chances and different number of runs.
What I tried to do is simplify it into fractions like 3/4 then multiply by 3 for the number of possibilities and three on the top also because that adds three times more possibilities to get to 9/12 but that is still 3/4 so I do not know how to solve it.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $A$ will occur at least once unless $B$ occurs all three runs, and the probability of that is $(1-.75)^3$

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

@J.W.Tanner assuming independence.  You then need to subtract your result from $1$

I agree, @Henry.  I was leaving that for OP to do

Could you also upvote my solutions if you found it useful?

The formula you’re looking for is
$$P(\text{$A$ at least once out of three})=1-(P(A^c))^n.$$
Here $P(A^c)=P(B)$.
It’s just
$$1-\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^3$$
Which is
$$1-\frac{1}{64}$$
Which is $\frac{63}{64}$.
Here, $\frac{1}{4}$ is the probability of $A$ not occurring which is denoted often as $A^c$ and is found by the formula $1-P(A)$. This is because total probability is $1$ and if occurrence is some percent $p$ then clearly, non occurrence is $1-p$. And since the answer is greater than the likely hood of $A$ which itself is more than half, and doing more times and asking for at least $1$ occurrence we should expect the answer to be closer to $1$ than the probability of $A$ itself for a single selection.
